# Uninstall Redis CentOS

Tags: redis, centos7, vps

I installed Redis on my CentOS 7 VPS. Now I want to remove it .

How can I remove it ?

I installed a time ago using the following commands:

- Log into your server via SSH
- Download the latest stable Redis release as a compressed file  wget
  http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
- Decompress the file  `tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz`
- Change into the uncompressed directory  `cd redis-stable`
- Run the make command:  `make`
- Complete the installation with this command:  `make install`

(If not logged in as root add a sudo before this command to make it sudo make install)

Comment: Can you try `make clean` or `make uninstall` command.

Comment: Change into the uncompressed directory `cd redis-stable` and try what @mchawre suggested above